# Wikidata SPARQL How to speed up this query?

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I have come to this query, which retrieves wikipedia and wikidata info from a wikipedia title:

```
SELECT ?wikipediaId ?wikipediaTitle ?wikidataId ?desc ?imageUrl
(GROUP_CONCAT(?instanceOfS; SEPARATOR=";") AS ?instancesOf)
(GROUP_CONCAT(?subclassOfS; SEPARATOR=";") AS ?subclassesOf)
(GROUP_CONCAT(?partOfS; SEPARATOR=";") AS ?partsOf)
(GROUP_CONCAT(?instanceOfLabel; SEPARATOR=";") AS ?instancesOfLabel)
(GROUP_CONCAT(?subclassOfLabel; SEPARATOR=";") AS ?subclassesOfLabel)
(GROUP_CONCAT(?partOfLabel; SEPARATOR=";") AS ?partsOfLabel)
WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "en.wikipedia.org".
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Generator".
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:generator "links".
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:titles "Albert Einstein".

    bd:serviceParam mwapi:prop "pageprops|description|pageimages".
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:piprop "thumbnail".
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:pithumbsize "300".
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:pilicense "any".

    ?wikipediaTitle wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:title.
    ?wikipediaId wikibase:apiOutput "@pageid".

    ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
    ?desc wikibase:apiOutput "@description".
    ?imageUrl wikibase:apiOutput "thumbnail/@source".
  }
  BIND (COALESCE(?item, "") AS ?vItem)
  OPTIONAL { ?vItem wdt:P31 ?instanceOf }
  OPTIONAL { ?vItem wdt:P279 ?subclassOf }
  OPTIONAL { ?vItem wdt:P361 ?partOf }

  BIND (STRAFTER(STR(?vItem), STR(wd:)) AS ?wikidataId)
  BIND (STRAFTER(STR(?instanceOf), STR(wd:)) AS ?instanceOfS)
  BIND (STRAFTER(STR(?subclassOf), STR(wd:)) AS ?subclassOfS)
  BIND (STRAFTER(STR(?partOf), STR(wd:)) AS ?partOfS)

  MINUS { ?vItem wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q17442446 }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?instanceOf rdfs:label ?instanceOfLabel.
    ?subclassOf rdfs:label ?subclassOfLabel. 
    ?partOf rdfs:label ?partOfLabel. }
} GROUP BY ?wikipediaId ?wikipediaTitle ?wikidataId ?desc ?imageUrl
```

It takes 13s for Albert Einstein, and 35s for Brazil.

I don't expect this to work too much fast, but I am sure this can be speeded up. I have read that the labels should be outside from this select, but even without the labels, the code still pretty slow. I have read that some sort of WITH blocks could help, but I haven't found too many examples.

What are the best ways to speed this up?